# openssl command generates an empty .key file from .pfx file

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, key, pfx

When I try to generate a key from a pfx certificate file, it creates an empty file

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -nocerts -out test.key -nodes
```

I executed the command on git bash, Windows server 2019. The command seems to run without stoping because I can't type.
Thanks